# $scope is not refreshing data inside template after $apply()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, object-literal

```
angular.module("mobApp.controllers")
.controller("ViewPostController",function($scope
  , $stateParams, Utils, PublishMessageService, $state, $ionicActionSheet, $ionicModal, Constants, ShareObjectService) {

  var postId = $stateParams.postId;
  $scope.post = {};
  $scope.BASE_URL = Constants.SERVER_URL;
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function() {
    $scope.utils = Utils;
    resetScopeVariables();
    loadPost();
  });

  $scope.reload = function() {
    loadPost();
  }

  $scope.vote = function(eventSource, voteType) {
    Utils.vote(eventSource, voteType, postId, postId);
  }

  loadPost = function() {
    resetScopeVariables();
    if(Utils.hasInternet()) {
      PublishMessageService.viewPublishMessage(postId).then(function(d){
        if(d.data.post) {
          $scope.showPost = true;
          $scope.post = d.data.post;         
          $scope.showContentLoading = false;
          ShareObjectService.setPostPhotoIds($scope.post.photosIds);
        } else {
          showInlineMessage(Utils.prepareErrorMessage("Nothing Was Found", "Sorry requested content is not available."));
        }       
      }, function(err) {
        showInlineMessage(Utils.prepareErrorMessage("Sorry!", err.description));
      });
    } else {
      showInlineMessage(Utils.prepareErrorMessage("Can't Connect", Constants.MSG_NO_INTERNET));
      $scope.showReloadBtn = true;
    }
  }

  $scope.showPostMoreOptions = function(postId) {
      $ionicActionSheet.show({
        buttons: [
          { text: '<i class="icon ion-edit"></i> Edit' },
          { text: '<i class="icon ion-trash-a"></i> Delete' }
        ],
        buttonClicked: function(index) {
          if(index === 0) {
        $state.go('app.publish-message-form', {'edit': true, 'postId': postId});        
          } else if(index === 1) {

          }
          return true;
        },
        destructiveButtonClicked: function() {
          return true;
        }
      }); 
  } 

  /*
    Utils function
  */

  function resetScopeVariables() {
    $scope = {
      pageInlineMsg: '',
      contentLoadingMessage: 'Loading..',
      showReloadBtn: false,
      showContentLoading: true,
      showPost: false
    };    
  }

  function showInlineMessage(msg) {
    $scope.pageInlineMsg = msg;
    $scope.showContentLoading = false;
  }
});
```

Here is my router

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url : '/app',
            abstract : true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/globalLeftMenu.html',
            controller: 'GlobalLeftMenuController'                
        })      
        .state('app.view-post', {
          url: '/view-post/:postId',
          views: {
            'app': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/publish_message/view_post.html',
                controller: 'ViewPostController'
            }
          }
        })
```

Here I am getting data for `$scope.post` but it is not reflecting in template. If I use `$scope.$apply()` then I get error `$scope.$apply is not a function`. I don't know why suddenly I start getting this kind of problem. Earlier it was working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with `$scope.$apply()` and change

```
function resetScopeVariables() {
    $scope = {
        pageInlineMsg: '',
        contentLoadingMessage: 'Loading..',
        showReloadBtn: false,
        showContentLoading: true,
        showPost: false
    };    
}
```

to

```
function resetScopeVariables() {
    $scope.pageInlineMsg = '';
    $scope.contentLoadingMessage = 'Loading..';
    $scope.showReloadBtn = false;
    $scope.showContentLoading = true;
    $scope.showPost = false;  
}
```

as previously you set `$scope` to an entirely new object and therefore you can't call `$scope.$apply` anymore.

Comment: Correct! setting `$scope = { ... }` - another object doesn't make any sense.. It's like a crime.. PO should have known that.

Comment: just changing `$scope ={}` to `$scope.fields` solved it. no need to do `$scope.$apply`